# Improve my "match a pattern from a directory and count" code

Tags: python-3.x, count, operating-system, pattern-matching, glob

I have this function that works just fine, but it only gives me the count of the files within the pattern or directory that I pass in.

```
import os
def fcount(path):
#Counts the number of files in a directory
count = 0
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
        count += 1
return count
```

---

```
path = "C:\\Users\\ca310\\Downloads\\" #Read files in folder
print (fcount(path))
```

---

output I get: 53 (whatever number of files I have in my downloads folder.

But I am trying to make it more efficient that if for example I change my path to

```
path = "C:\\Users\\ca310\\Downloads\\*.txt"
```

then it would give me the count of all the .txt files in that folder, but it doesnt work.
Any hits?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question, even being an interesting thing to discuss do not fully meet SO guidelines. If I'm right what you are asking is why using `"C:\\Users\\ca310\\Downloads\\*.txt"` isn't working with your code. You should make it more obvious in your question. Right now it feels like you are asking the community help to write your code where SO is only a question/answer forum.

Comment: not exactly, but I see your point.
What I'm trying to achieve is have a better quality code where instead of just having the current function where it does return the number of files in a folder, how can I make it that it also returns the number of any pattern that I input for example *.txt or *.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character), you should use [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

```
from glob import glob
glob("C:\\Users\\ca310\\Downloads\\*.txt")
```